# Can USART TX on the STM32f4 be open-drain?

Tags: uart, stm32f4

I'm retrofitting an old project, moving a Discovery Board from an isolated ground to a non-isolated ground, and it's shifting around all my power supplies.

This will be interfacing with a 5V device that probably won't deal well with a 3V TX from the Discovery.  I'm using USART3 on C10 and C11, which are 5V tolerant, so RX shouldn't be an issue.  Now, since the level shift is no longer handled by my isolator, I'm just trying to find out if I can get away with an open drain output and a pull up resistor for TX, or do I need to use a more elaborate level shifter.  Seems like it shouldn't be an issue, but every usart example I've seen on for UART on STM32F4 using Push/Pull outs.

UPDATE:
This worked just fine.  I bench tested, and didn't see any problems.  Once I actually had everything hooked up,  it seems like something on the output had a bigger capacitive load than my bench test, impacting my TX at my  megabaud rate, but lowering the pullup resistor fixed this.

Comment: Seems you have two different questions - if the chip will functionally let you configure the output as open drain when using an alternative function, which I suspect it will, and then if doing so electrically makes sense for your application.

Comment: @ChrisStratton-- it makes absolute sense for my application.  I know I can set the output port to be open drain, but I don't know if that's allowed when the pin is set to be USART.  The only reason why my app wouldn't be able to use this config is if the STM32F4 won't support that mode.

Comment: It's not clear what question you are expecting anyone to answer here.  It's easy to determine if the chip will let you configure it that way, if using it in your application is electrically valid beyond what the data sheet says is something probably no one but the engineer at ST who designed it could say.  You can for example see if a weak pullup resistor will let you raise the pin above VDDIO, but I'm not sure that there will be any difference between GPIO and AF mode.  Those two settings are in distinct registers in this subfamily, right?

Comment: @ChrisStratton-  the relevant part of the Data Sheet says "Each of the GPIO pins can be configured by software as output (push-pull or open-drain ..., as input (floating...) or as peripheral alternate function.  The examples all show the GPIO setup (where you can set the outputs to open drain) and the USART setup as separate.  I'd like to know if the USART setup will undo an open-drain setting, because of the data sheet language.  I suppose a quick test is the way to go, but I'm off site and was hoping someone would know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the typical STM32F4 library API defines a "mode" for GPIO which encompasses both the gpio vs. alternate function selection and the push-pull vs open-drain selection, these actually have distinct configuration bits at hardware level, and a define or enum for an open drain alternate function is provided.

However, this is distinct from the question if an open drain alternate function (USART) setting is electrically appropriate to your circuit goals.

Answer (score 1):

The UART Tx pin can indeed be set to Open Drain or Push-Pull by selecting the proper argument to the GPIOInit() function.

I am working on an STM32 based project and I also needed to have the Tx pin as open drain, which I achieved by changing a single line in the definitions before calling GPIOInit() as follows:

from

```
gpioa_init_struct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
```

to

```
gpioa_init_struct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_OD;
```